Removed 'root' user from Sudoers file, but still able to avail root user privileges after removing the root user from Sudoers file

The above screenshot is the snippet of the Sudoers file, displaying the root user having the access to elevated privileges. I deleted that line where it says "root ALL=(ALL) ALL", so that I am removing the sudo privileges to the root user.
But after doing that, I am still able to avail the sudo privileges (example: installing a package, creating a user as a root user).
My doubt is how is it happening in the background when I have deleted the root user from Sudoers file and I am still able to sudo privileges for the root user.

When you say you create a user or install a package as root, is it by prefixing the commands by sudo when logged in as root?  Is there another active line of configuration in your sudoers file? Could you give examples of commands you think should not work and also say what user executes those commands?

The sudoers file is only relevant to the command sudo. That line is there only to allow the root user to run sudo command without needing a password. It doesn't affect the permissions of the actual root user, and if you have logged in as root or switched to root using su or sudo -i, you can still run commands without needing sudo. All that line changes is that if you try to run sudo as root, it will block you:
# sudo ls
root is not in the sudoers file.

However, it will have no effect if you just try to run a command without sudo since the root user already has all privileges.
Now, if you mean that you can still run sudo commands while logged in as root, then you probably have another line in your sudoers file that gives sudo rights to a group that the root user belongs to. Usually, on most systems, sudo access is set by group and there is a specific group or groups whose members are allowed to run sudo commands. The most common such groups are wheel and sudo. For example, on my Arch system, I have:
$ sudo grep '%.*ALL=(ALL)' /etc/sudoers
%wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL
# %wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
# %sudo ALL=(ALL) ALL

The liens that start with a # are ignored, they are comments. The line %wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL means that all members of the wheel group have the right to run all sudo commands. And, indeed, the root user of my systems belongs to that group:
$ sudo groups
root bin daemon sys adm disk wheel log

So even after removing root ALL=(ALL) ALL, the line that explicitly gives the root user the right to use sudo, since root belongs to wheel, the %wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL line allows root to use sudo. You would need to comment that line out as well if you don't want root to be able to use sudo.
Note that on many systems, you will see the sudo group used instead of wheel, I believe Ubuntu does that for example. The same situation applies though, and you would have a %sudo    ALL=(ALL) ALL line in your /etc/sudoers file.
